# Change shouldReceiveTouch return value while touching

Tags: cocoa-touch

Well, let me explain my problem.
I have to change the return value of

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch { }
```

while I am moving my Finger (Touch) and not only setting the value at the Beginning of a touch.

Is this possible? If yes how?
Please help.

Comment: Is that important to change the return value of THIS method ? Because you could call a personal function in this method instead.

Comment: i figured it out, thank you anyway

Comment: I think you should post your answer so it will be more readable for other users :)

Comment: have had to wait 6 hours before answering my own question ^^ 30 minutes left

Answer (score 0):

Once the touch recognizing is started, this method won't be called again. If you just want to *cancel* the gesture, just call

```
gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

This will cancel the current gesture.

However, there might be better solutions depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

So, figured it out, what i did is following:

I have created a global boolean variable
Then I used

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer { }
```

insted of

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch { }
```

using the `UIPanGestureRegocnizer` i am setting the variable to `TRUE` or `FALSE` depents on what I am doing.

I am displaying Alerts and other things, using this method executed my alert code multiple times, therefore I have defined another Boolean variable so i can check if the alert is shown, to display it only one time :)

That was my workaround solution..
Fixed a bug, yey ^^